# Swift: Change Simulator Location programmatically

Tags: ios, swift, ios-simulator, gpx

I am looking for a way to change the `Simulator` location programatically.

I know that I can Use a `GPX` file and then select it in the `Xcode` teleport option however this is not what I want.

There seems to be either little information or a definite answer if this is possible and I am struggling to think of solutions.

Can anyone help?

If I have to create several `GPX` files and then switch them programmatically that is fine.

Comment: I don't think this is possible.

Comment: is there a way to do it on the device?

Comment: I am not sure, I feel like we need to add the GPX anyways. If so, then we can edit the GPX file in the run-time programatically and then try to use it. While building edit the scheme and provide this GPX file for Location Simulation.

Answer (score 2):

Im afraid there is no easy way to do this. This has been asked quite a lot and you can see other posts with the same answers.

The best way you can automate this is to:

1. create all the `GPX` files you need with the different locations
2. create a build script that selects the appropriate one
3. use a build server to build the product and run the XCTests for each one

You can search high and low and you will end up with a variation of this method. Good luck! :)

Comment: is there no simple way to load a different gpx for different views? I would like to swipe through view segues and then load the gpx. I am rather new to ios and terminology and understanding is not my strong point. pointers welcome :)

Answer (score 0):

While setting from code is not available, there is a CLI tool [set_simulator_location](https://github.com/MobileNativeFoundation/set-simulator-location) that works great for development testing